# Windows 8 PRO - prevent user from closing application

Tags: windows, privileges

I would like to run an application (in background [system tray] or just a normal windows application it does not matter) on the normal user account on Windows 7/8 PRO - but I would like to prevent the user from closing it (e.g. if somebody clicks "close" the alert box should be showed with something like "access denied" or "grant administrator privileges prompt", like when copying to a location without permission).

Is there a possibility to run that application on startup as administrator, so the current normal user cannot really use the application? Does Windows PRO has such thing implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run your application as service (like TeamViewer does). So when someone tries close the application it just restarts. 
You could try to use [srvstart.exe](http://rozanski.org.uk/services) to run the application as service.